# Template override from sub-sub-theme does not work

Tags: 7, theming

I try to override a specific content type node template. Let's say `node--some-type.tpl.php`. I use the `mothership` as a base theme based on that I defined a sub-theme let's call it `A`.

Overriding the template in `A` works perfectly fine. Now I like to create another sub-theme based on the `A` sub-theme let's call it `B`.

Overriding the same template (`node--some-type.tpl.php`) doesn't work anymore. It always takes the overridden template file from sub-theme `A` instead of `B`.

Is there any special thing I have to respect when I like to override a template file in a sub-sub-theme?

I deleted theme registry multiple times and cleaned the whole cache using `drush cc`.

Any ideas why this does not work?

Comment: basic check: 1) are all of those themes enabled? 2) is `B` set as default? 3) is `B` lists `A` as `base theme` in `.info` file?

Comment: @oksana-c yes everything seems to be correct...